# Another derivative of an integral question.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, bifurcation

**Edit: look at the picture at the bottom first. I'm meddling with exercise 2.**

**Please answer avoiding ODEs, since this course comes before ODEs in my school.**

So far, my asnwer to ex. 1 is the following:

I have a two variable scalar function $f$ such that $f(x_0,y)=x_0$ for every $y$, i.e. $x_0$ is a fixed point of $f$ for any $y$.

I have proved that there is a function $f_1(x,y)$ such that $f(x,y)=x_0 + f_1(x,y)(x-x_0),$ in the following way:

$$f(x,y)-x_0=f(x,y)-f(x_0,y)= \int_{x_0}^x \frac{d}{dx} f(z,y) dz,$$

and applying the change of variable $z = x_0 + t(x-x_0)$, which gives $t=0$ when $z = x_0$ and $t=1$ for $z= x$; and $dz= (x-x_0)dt$, we get:

$$\int_{x_0}^x \frac{d}{dx} f(z,y) dz = \int_0^1 \frac{d}{dx} f(x_0 +t(x-x_0),y) dt (x-x_0).$$

Then the demanded function is $f_1(x,y) = \int_0^1 \frac{d}{dx} f(x_0 +t(x-x_0),y) dt$.

Now, I'm asked to **take the first and second partial derivatives with respect to $x$ and $y$ of $f_1(x,y)$**, using (some of) the sufficient and/or non-degeneracy conditions for a transcritical bifurcation:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x_0,y)=1,$$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x_0,y)=0,$$
$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}f(x_0,y)\neq1,$$
$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}f(x_0,y) \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^y}f(x_0,y) - \Big(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x y}f(x_0,y)\Big)^2 < 0.$$

I'm completely stuck at this point, I visited and revisited the fisrt and second fundamental theorem of calculus but I still can't fugire it out. Can you help me?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: this is the exercise in which this problem appears:

[image]

Comment: This is muddled and impossible to follow. What are the hypotheses and what is the desired conclusion? Moreover, you write $\dfrac{\partial f(x_0,y)}{\partial x}$, which is of course identically $0$. What must you write instead?

Comment: Thanks, for the warning. I've edited this, I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: I will make my point more explicitly: If you want the derivative of $f$ at $x_0$ you write $\dfrac{df}{dx}\Big|_{x=x_0}$ or $\dfrac{df}{dx}(x_0)$, not $\dfrac d{dx}f(x_0)$, because $f(x_0)$ is *always* a constant.

Comment: So what, explicitly, is the implicit function theorem criterion you need in order to write $f_1(x,y) = 1$ locally as $x=x_*(y)$ near $(x_0,y_0)$? I have no idea why you're writing down the Hessian determinant.